# Как ограничить количество итераций цикла for

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно из объекта в котором 50 товаров вывести в блок только 4. Используя for(let key in goods)

Ниже пример JSON

```js
    const goods = {
    "10001": {
    "name": "Шорти",
    "cost": 99,
    "size": "L",
    "color": "Black",
    "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
    "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10002": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 299,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10003": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 199,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10004": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10005": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 499,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10006": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 599,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10007": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 39,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10008": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 398,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10009": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 397,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10010": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 396,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10011": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 395,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10012": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 394,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10013": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 393,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10014": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 392,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10015": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 391,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10016": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 390,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10017": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10018": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10019": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10020": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10021": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10022": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10023": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10024": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10025": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10026": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10027": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10028": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10029": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10030": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10031": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10032": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10033": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10034": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10035": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10036": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10037": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10038": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10039": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10040": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10041": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10042": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10043": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10044": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10045": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10046": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10047": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10048": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10049": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    },
    "10050": {
        "name": "Шорти",
        "cost": 399,
        "size": "L",
        "color": "Black",
        "discription": "Шорты Puma Ess Jersey Shorts 58670601 XL Black",
        "image": "images/167433686.jpg"
    }
    }
```

Comment: создайте счетчик и каждую итерацию его увеличивайте. Как дойдете до 4-х выполняете команду `break`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для прерывания цикл **for** по условию, необходимо использовать директиву **break**:

```js
const dataIn = {
  1: 11,
  2: 12,
  3: 13,
  4: 14,
  5: 15,
  6: 16,
};

let j = 0;
for (let i in dataIn) {
  // Что то делаем с данными
  console.log(i, dataIn[i]);
  // Увеличиваем счетчик
  if (++j === 4) break; // прерываем цикл
}
```

UPD: *из комментариев* - Для пропуска итераций в цикле используется директива **continue**

```js
const dataIn = {
  1: 11,
  2: 12,
  3: 13,
  4: 14,
  5: 15,
  6: 16,
};

let j = 0;
for (let i in dataIn) {
  j++;
  if (j < 2) continue; //Пропускаем итерацию
  // Что то делаем с данными
  console.log(i, dataIn[i]);
  // Увеличиваем счетчик
  if (j === 5) break; // Прерываем цикл
}
```

Comment: `++j` никогда не будет больше чем 4, потому можно просто строгое равенство поставить

Comment: Спасибо! А если нужно с 10 по 20, то счетчик ставить let j = 10;
for (let i in dataIn) {
  // Что то делаем с данными
  console.log(i, dataIn[i]);
  // Увеличиваем счетчик
  if (++j >= 20) break; // прерываем цикл
}

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а если нужно вывести четыре рандомных товара, то это можно реализовать в цикле for in?

Comment: @ВячеславСиваш Если надо с 10, то счетчик все равно должен начинаться с 0. Для пропуска итераций есть `continue`. Можно выводить и рандомные данные, но использование цикла не рационально будет и тут нужен другой подход

Comment: спасибо, вроде разобрался - сохранил данные вывода из цикла в массив

Comment: спасибо, вроде разобрался - 
let newGoods = [];
for(var key in goods){
var out = `<div class="block2-container-card">
<button data-art"${key}">Add to CARD</button></div>`
newGoods.push(out);
};
let result = [];
getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
while (result.length != 4) {
    let index = getRandomInt(newGoods.length);    
    result.push(newGoods[index]);    
    result = result.filter((v, i, arr) =>  arr.indexOf(v) == i);
};
result.forEach((item) => {
  goodsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', out);
});
или это бред?

Comment: @EzioMercer Да... перебдил ) Поправил для красоты